# VSCode - How to delete a specific command history in command palette (as opposed to clearing everything)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-history

I would like to delete several commands from VSCode command palette's "recently used" section, but not clear the entire history. How?

---

So in Chrome's Omnibar, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> to delete a suggestion. But I cannot find an analogous shortcut in VSCode's command palette.

I also looked for a "meta-command" for this, but I only found `Clear Command History` in the command palette. I want something like `Edit/Manage Command History` instead.

---

Edit: a history file that I can directly edit (analogous to `~/.bash_history` for Bash) would also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the [response by cyqsimon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75000891/10871073); but, for Windows, it's (on my machine) located under:

```
%AppData%\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb
```

This is a SQLite database file, and can for example be opened and edited with SQLite DB Browser.

So, close Visual Studio Code, and the entry key in this database file that needs to be changed is:

```
commandPalette.mru.cache
```

And, if you want to clear everything, you can (at least with the current version at the time of writing) change its value to this Json:

```
{"usesLRU":true, "entries":[]}
```

If you just want some of them you need to edit the json values as you see fit. You might also want to reset:

```
commandPalette.mru.counter
```

and set its value to `1`. Or however many entries you choose to keep in the json `entries` list +1 (at least it seems that way after a bit trial and error). But if you don't clear the list completely in the previous json-chunk you probably want to change the numbers referenced there too.

Save the file and restart Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I'll switch the accepted answer to this one since it's much easier than my convoluted mess of a method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this question was upvoted today, which brought it back to my attention. I decided to bite the bullet this time and dug into the nuts and bolts of VSCode's files and found where this history is stored.

### TLDR

Modifying the history is doable (obviously, because it has to be stored ***somewhere***), but it's not very practical at all. Unfortunately it will continue to be very difficult, until VSCode implements official support (which may be never). I recommend using the following method **ONLY IF** you ***absolutely*** need a history entry deleted.

---

### The method

**Note:**

- I'm using Code OSS (the debranded build of VSCode) on Linux. The method should be applicable to other OSes, but the specific commands and paths will be different.
- This method works on VSCode 1.74.2, the latest version as of 2023-01-04. It may or may not work with future versions.

##### 0. Exit VSCode completely

Obviously.

Check with your resource/task/process manager to make sure VSCode is completely killed. If you're not sure, just reboot.

##### 1. Locate `lastSyncglobalState.json`

This file contains the command palette history data. On Linux it's located at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/Code - OSS/User/sync/globalState/lastSyncglobalState.json`. On Windows it's probably under a similar path in `%APPDATA%`. Not sure about MacOS. Copy this file to somewhere convenient.

If you are curious how I discovered this file, I did a search of a command I recently ran using `rg` in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/Code - OSS/`. Note that you have to search the "programmatic name" of the command, not its display name (e.g. `rust-analyzer.reload`, not `rust-analyzer: Restart server`).

##### 2. Extract the relevant data

If you open up `lastSyncglobalState.json` with a text editor directly, you'll find a Russian doll of escaped JSON. Technically you ***can*** do the modification straight from here, but I'm not eating this .

Fortunately `jq` makes this somewhat easier:

```bash
# This is Bash but I think it works on Windows CMD too? Not sure.
jq '.syncData.content | fromjson.storage."commandPalette.mru.cache".value | fromjson.entries' lastSyncglobalState.json > history.json
```

The extracted `history.json` should look something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "rust-analyzer.debug",
    "value": 297
  },
  {
    "key": "rust-analyzer.syntaxTree",
    "value": 298
  },
  // more entries...
]
```

##### 3. Modify

Copy `history.json` to `history-new.json`, and simply remove the entries you want to delete from `history-new.json`. **Do not** modify `history.json`; we will need it in a bit.

Check that it's still valid JSON after your edits; in particular make sure that you have not left a trailing comma in the array.

##### 4. Write back

The ***responsible*** way to do this is to perform the inverse of step 2, starting from the bottom up, update a field, json-encode, then update the field one level up, json-encode again, etc, until we get to the top level. But that's an enormous pain in the arse to do with `jq`.

Much easier I think, simply double (triple?) json-encode `history-new.json`, and perform a textual replacement. This is where the original `history.json` comes in handy:

```bash
# In lastSyncglobalState.json, replace the output of...
jq 'tojson | tojson' history.json

# with the output of...
jq 'tojson | tojson' history-new.json
```

Note that since the output of `jq` is quoted, it's necessary to remove the outmost layer of quotes (`"`) on both the search string and the replace string. With `rg` we can automate this:

```bash
jq 'tojson | tojson' history.json | rg '^"(.+)"$' -r '$1'
jq 'tojson | tojson' history-new.json | rg '^"(.+)"$' -r '$1'
```

Of course there's nothing wrong with doing it manually, or with using `sed` instead if you want to. Again, just be careful you're not creating invalid JSON.

##### 5. Copy back into VSCode directory

Honestly, you probably want to make a backup of the entire `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/Code - OSS/` directory (or whatever it is on your machine) before doing this. It's probably big I know, but I'm not sure what crazy thing VSCode will do if it finds `lastSyncglobalState.json` unparseable. Better be safe than sorry.

After you've done that, just copy your modified `lastSyncglobalState.json` back into `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/Code - OSS/User/sync/globalState/lastSyncglobalState.json` and voila.

Answer (score -3):

VSCode terminal uses external shell. For linux the default shell it's bash, for windows it's powershell.

If your terminal shell is powershell, go to `C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline` on your file explorer

Visit this [link](https://0xdf.gitlab.io/2018/11/08/powershell-history-file.html) for more details, if the above does not help.

Comment: Unfortunately this is completely unrelated to what I'm looking for.